Absoluteness of inaccessible cardinals
I'm studying large cardinals and I'm hoping to fully understand the proof that says ZFC is not able to prove the existence of inaccessibles (given ZFC is consistent, of course).
I've already fully understood and/or proven everything up to and including: if we had an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, then $V_\kappa$ is a (sub)model of ZFC. I also understood the main proof that takes the least inaccessible $\kappa$ and arrives at a contradiction by finding another inaccessible inside $V_\kappa$.
The only thing that's missing is the following Lemma:
Given a model $M$ of ZFC and an inaccessible $\kappa$, $\lambda$ is inaccessible in $M$ iff it is inaccessible in $V_\kappa\subset M$.
I feel like the proof of this lemma is highly technical and that I'm getting confused about the relativization of the axioms and the absoluteness of the functions and properties needed to define cardinals and inaccessibility.
I haven't found a proof anywhere. Does anyone know a good reference for this lemma?
Thanks in advance!

Do you have a reference for this lemma? it doesn't quite make sense as written.

I imagine you just want to know why an inaccessible relative to $V_\kappa$ as actually a real inaccessible below $\kappa$? (and the phrasing of the lemma is an XY problem)

The lemma can be found on page 10 of this document: https://minterscompactness.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/lc-2022.pdf

It says that the claim is that $\lambda$ is inaccessible iff $V_\kappa\models$ "$\kappa$ is inaccessible", so I think I am confused about needing a model $M$ to talk about this result. Cause, what does it mean that $V_\kappa\models$ "something" if we don't have a model $M$ that contains an inaccessible $\kappa$? Where does $\kappa$ live if not in a model?

We're just proving things in ZFC, i.e. "If $\kappa$ is inaccessible and $\lambda < \kappa$ is an ordinal and $V_\kappa\models$ "$\lambda$ is inaccessible", then $\lambda$ is inaccessible" is a theorem of ZFC. This will be a true statement inside any model of ZFC, of course, but adding an "extra layer" of models isn't necessary.

But what does it mean that $V_\kappa\models$ "$\lambda$ is inaccessible"? To talk about $V_\kappa$ semantically satisfying a formula, we have to think of it as a set, not as a syntactic object that is defined by a series of formulas, right? So we're really talking about $V_\kappa$ as a subset of a given model, are we not?

The satisfaction relation can be formalized in ZFC. (And this is the sense in which "$V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC" as well, which is important. e.g. it's not obvious the "Godel's theorem" approach from earlier in those notes can work unless the satisfaction is internal.)

I see. In that case, do you have any reference I could look up for that lemma?

That the satisfaction relation can be formalized, or the original lemma of interest?

Mainly the lemma of interest. But if you also have one for the formalization of satisfaction in ZFC, that would be helpful too.

As discussed in the comments, what we want to prove is:

If $\kappa$ is inaccessible and $\lambda < \kappa$ then $V_\kappa\models \mbox{"$\lambda$ is inaccessible"},$ if and only if $\lambda$ is inaccessible.

Really we only need the forward direction to show $\sf ZFC\not\vdash \exists inaccessibles$, so that's the one we'll prove (the other direction is similar). We can just prove it for "regular" and "strong limit" separately. The high-level reason is that $V_\kappa$ "knows everything" that goes on below rank $\kappa$ and any potential witnesses contradicting the inaccessibility of $\lambda<\kappa$ would have rank $<\kappa,$ so $V_\kappa$ would know about them if they existed.
(This same idea works pretty much verbatim for any large cardinal property that is "witnessed locally", e.g. weak compactness, measurability. For instance, we can use a similar argument to show that if it's consistent that measurable cardinals exist, then it's consistent that there's only one and that it's the greatest inaccessible.)
If $\lambda$ is not regular, there is some sequence $\lambda_\alpha\uparrow \lambda$ for $\alpha < \beta$ where $\beta < \lambda.$ Well, then $(\lambda_\alpha: \alpha< \beta)\in V_\kappa$ and $V_\kappa\models \lambda_\alpha\uparrow \lambda,$ so $V_\kappa\models \mbox{"$\lambda$ is not regular"}.$
Likewise, if $\lambda$ is not a strong limit, there is an $\alpha < \lambda$ and a surjection $g:P(\alpha)\to \lambda$, but then $\lambda, \alpha, P(\alpha), g\in V_\kappa$ and $$V_\kappa\models \mbox{"$P(\alpha)$ is the power set of $\alpha<$, $\alpha < \lambda$ and $g:P(\alpha)\to \lambda$ is a surjection"}$$ so $V_\kappa\models \mbox{"$\lambda$ is not a strong limit."}$
Note we didn't use that $\kappa$ was inaccessible in any significant way (for this part - of course it's important for showing $V_\kappa\models \sf ZFC$), we just implicitly used that it was a limit ordinal in a couple places.

So it's just about seeing that $V_\kappa$ has the same ordinals as the ordinals $\alpha<\kappa$, and that every function $f:\alpha\to\lambda$ is exactly the same in $V_\kappa$ and vice-versa. Am I right?

@Darsen The properties of being an ordinal or a function $\alpha \to \lambda$ are absolute for any transitive model. The crucial thing here, specific to models of the form $V_\kappa$, that gives them very strong absoluteness properties is, e.g., that every function of that sort is an element of $V_\kappa$... it isn't missing any set of rank below $\kappa$.
